# Django custom dropdown depending on field type

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the models:

```
class DeepLink(models.Model):

    class DeepLinkType(models.TextChoices):
                TRACING = ('Tracing', 'Tracing')
                BUTTON = ('Button', 'Button')
                MODAL = ('Modal', 'Modal')
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=DeepLinkType.choices, blank=False)
    uri = models.UUIDField(blank=False, default=uuid4)
    
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'deeplink'

class Button(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'button'


class Modal(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'modal'

class Tracing(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    external = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    external_link = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tracing'
```

I need to have a dropdown for the field `uri` in the Django Admin depending on `type` have chosen. For example, if we choose `type` as `Button`, the `uri` field should be a dropdown for all possible buttons etc.

Obviously I can't declare `uri` as foreign key because it can refer to 3 tables. Hence it's just a text field in the admin now.

How is it possible to make such dynamic dropdown in Django Admin?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect use for Generic Foreign Keys. In general, it's recommended to use them sparingly, but this is the sort of application they were made for.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/13/how-to-use-generic-relations.html